# Read Original Data from Signed content java

Tags: java, x509

I want to extract original data from signed content.

In the following code, the signed data is "CMSSignedData signed"

I found several similar answers from the StackOverflow, but all the answers cannot
state how to extract original data from signed content.

regards

```
package chapter9;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessable;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;

/**
 * Example of generating a detached signature.
 */
public class SignedDataExample
    extends SignedDataProcessor
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore        credentials = Utils.createCredentials();
        PrivateKey      key = (PrivateKey)credentials.getKey(Utils.END_ENTITY_ALIAS, Utils.KEY_PASSWD);
    Certificate[]   chain = credentials.getCertificateChain(Utils.END_ENTITY_ALIAS);
    CertStore       certsAndCRLs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
                        new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Arrays.asList(chain)), "BC");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[0];

    // set up the generator
    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

    gen.addSigner(key, cert, CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA256);
    gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certsAndCRLs);

    // create the signed-data object

    CMSProcessable  data = new CMSProcessableByteArray("Hello World!".getBytes());
    CMSSignedData signed = gen.generate(data, "BC");

    // recreate
    signed = new CMSSignedData(data, signed.getEncoded());

    //extract public key
    CertStore cs = signed.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");



    //signed.signedContent
    //signed.g
    CMSProcessable S = signed.getSignedContent();
    String aaa = S.getContent().toString();
    //byte[] K = Base64.decodeBase64((S.getContent()).toString());



    //
    //String K = Base64.decodeBase64(S.getContent());
    //BASE64Decoder.decoder.decodeBuffer()

    //
    //byte[] array = asString.getBytes("UTF8");
    //String s = new String(array, "UTF8");

    // verification step
    X509Certificate rootCert = (X509Certificate)credentials.getCertificate(Utils.ROOT_ALIAS);

    if (isValid(signed, rootCert))
    {
        System.out.println("verification succeeded");
        //System.out.println(K);
        //String asString = new String((byte[])data.getContent());
        //String asString1 = new String(cs.toString());
        //System.out.println(asString);
        //System.out.println(asString1);
        //System.out.println(aaa);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("verification failed");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the aaa prints [B@fa7e74 not Hello World

Comment: Have You tried: http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.html#generate%28org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData%29 ? because pkcs-7 can create a detached signature wich means original data is not contained in signature.. And how about new String(aaa) ?

Comment: @user1349407 "[B@fa7e74" looks like the toString output of a byte array. Have you tried printing/logging the class of S.getContent()? Applying toString to that object as you do might simply throw away any content, e.g. if the object is an array. If the class turns out to be a byte[], print the individual bytes to check whether they represent the data you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `String aaa = new String(s);` instead of `String aaa = S.getContent().toString();` although you should also specify an encoding, e.g. `String aaa = new String(s, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`. Please do the same for your `toBytes()` methods.

Comment: @MagnoC That not a very useful remark... but I'll add it to my list of erroneous error messages.

Comment: Sorry. I'll explain: You said we need to use `String aaa = new String(s);` but the `s` (lowercase) came from where? Clarify your answer please.

Comment: @MagnoC I presume I automatically converted the uppercase S to lowercase s as Java coding standards indicate.

Comment: Yeap, but I can't cast `CMSProcessable` (s) to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new String((byte[])S.getContent());` to get the original content